# Как узнать сколько юнитов прошел AI unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

Мне надо узнать сколько юнитов прошел AI и записать это в переменную (это должно происходить в реальном времени) возможно есть какой-то алгоритм?

Comment: Из вашего описания совсем не понятно, что значит "сколько юнитов прошёл AI". Могу лишь предположить, что вам нужен какой-то счётчик в том месте, где АИ "Проходит юнитов", с возможностью посмотреть этот счётчик снаружи

Comment: Мне надо узнать какое расстояние прошел АИ и возможность посмотреть этот счётчик снаружи

Comment: если что, то на будущее юнит - это персонаж. Машинка, вояка, маг. Поэтому в вопросе нужно было указывать вместо заумных слов более понятные и себе и другим -- "какую дистанцию прошел персонаж"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял:
Запишите точку входа/появления/начала отсчета бота, а при запросе "Сколько прошел этот кусок пластика?" считать расстояние между А(public или GetComponentName{Get{}}) и Б(да тоже самое, что и А, но у объекта).

```
if (Vector3.Distance(startPos, transform.position) > 1)
Debug.Log("+1");
```